# Heavy Load Application Freezes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, event-handling

We have a Client-server C# application which freezes when we create 1000 and more kind of objects in UI by using some scripts rather than creating it in UI individually.

We are using lot of event handlers for certain event, but as per my understanding all threads(UI and background) and event handlers are managing properly. Then also our client application freezes. We dont know what the exact reason behind it .
 Peak time hanging application took around 16 threads.  Task Manager reports it taking more than 90% CPU time.

Can any body tell me the reason behind it

```
   [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.DoEvents();
            Application.Run(new Test());
        }
```

**UPDATE**

How can i applay lazy loading to Treeview,Listview,and propertygrid.I have used beginupdate,endupdate,double buffering,other than these any methods??

**UPDATE**

what does high CPU utilization means, my application exe is hanging with 13 threads and some place i heard that if you use `ThreadPriority.Lowest` it will reduce CPU utilization, will it work still i dont know where to use it properly??

Comment: Does it ever "unfreeze", or it remains "frozen" forever?

Comment: with the information given, we can only guess. you may be running out of GUI resources.

Comment: Try to create a minimal reproduction of the problem, and then post the code. As it is, we are limited to guesses.

Comment: @Brook after 5 or 6 minutues it will recover bacome normal and will add all thoses 1000 objects

Comment: These objects are controls? Sounds like a good candidate for lazy loading, i.e. loading the items on demand as the user scrolls down the page.

Comment: UI is  left side  created by treeview, right is with listview and tab contains property grid and user controls

Comment: Profile the app with the minimum load that reproduces the problem.  if you are CPU-bound then profiling should point you towards design mods that will help, or else you will know you need more hardware.

Comment: Probably if you suggest me what are the things taken care ,that will be useful

Comment: Is the front end in WPF or Winforms?  If WPF (and assuming that that the problem is creating thousands of controls), then you could use a WPF container that uses a Virtualizing Stack Panel (like a list box with a DataTemplate) to handle the Lazy Loading of controls that James Johnson wrote about in his comment.

Comment: +1 to JMarsch. We saw incredible performance gains using a Virtualizing Stack Panel with as little as 30 items (though each "item" was a row with a display template consisting of a dozen fields or so).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need some sort of lazy loading technique to load the controls on demand as the user scrolls down the form. Loading that many controls at once will inevitably lock the application up.

This article offers some good tips on how to improve the performance of winform apps:

- [Practical Tips For Boosting The Performance Of Windows Form Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163630.aspx)

Comment: i checked this link,and verified with  my application that almost all of them are already used. Still it got hang when creating sudden objects through any Script or any bat file or through OS named pipe. That time it takes more than 90 % of CPU time .An one more thing when objects are creating some kind of automation also going on

Comment: How can i applay lazy loading to Treeview,Listview,and propertygrid.I have used beginupdate,endupdate,double buffering,other than these any methods??

Comment: what does high CPU utilization means, my application exe is hanging with 13 threads and some place i heard that if you use ThreadPriority.Lowest it will reduce CPU utilization, will it work still i dont know where to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

Treeviews and Listviews are not very efficient on their own and without adding lots of logic. If you don't have time to optemise them, you may want to check out 3rd party solutions like the AMAZING open source ObjectListView.

It comes in a few flavours to handle specific situations like FastObjectListView which handles millions of records or the TreeListView to handle heirarchy!

It does take a bit of effort to master but nowhere near what it takes to make Treeviews and Listviews into.. well ObjectListViews :D

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#what-flavour-of-objectlistview-do-i-want-to-use

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html

I've used it in a few projects myself with great success!!

Cheers,

Comment: what does high CPU utilization means, my application exe is hanging with 13 threads and some place i heard that if you use ThreadPriority.Lowest it will reduce CPU utilization, will it work still i dont know where to use it properly